# Ubiqity Preseed, to have aligned partitions on disk

Tags: installation, ubiquity

I tried to use the expert_reciepe to have aligned partitions on a High capacity disk with 4096b block size.

```
ubiquity    partman/alignment select optimal
ubiquity    partman-auto/disk string /dev/sdb
ubiquity    partman-auto/choose_recipe select myboot-part
ubiquity    partman-auto/expert_recipe string             \
      myboot-part ::                                            \
              10240 1049 10240 ext4                                  \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format }     format{ }          \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              16384 8172 16384 linux-swap                         \
                      $primary{ } method{ swap }                 \
              .                                               \
              30720 10240 30720 ext4                          \
                      $primary{ } method{ format }     format{ }               \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /backup_fs }                     \
              .                                               \
              10240 10240 10000000 ext4                           \
                      $primary{ } method{ format }     format{ }               \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /home }                     \
              .
```

And I was expecting the preseed `partman/alignment select optimal` should have allowed me to have aligned partitions on the disk. But the partitions are **not aligned.**

Alternatively , I use a script to partition the disk to have aligned partitions in it. And then run the Ubiquity with the preseed file to make use the existing partitions. The partitions I created are for `/`, `/home` and `swap`. But I don't know how to achieve this using a Preseed file.

I've tried reading through guides for preseeding and customization, but I did not understand how and where to modify the pressed options to make use of the existing partitions on the disk.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!